# Reference to project with service reference: Unknown endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, wcf-endpoint

I have:

1. WCF Service [Application 1]
2. Logic communicating with this service [Project1 Application2]
3. Web Page using this logic [Project2 Application2]

In *Logic* project I added service reference to *Service*.
In *WebPage* I added project reference to *Logic*.

Now endpoints to *Service* are definied in *Logic* project so I cannot connect to *Service* from *WebPage*.

I know that I solution is to copy part of *Logic* config to *WebPage* config, but I don't think it's a good solution.

I would like to have *Logic* as a black box. I don't know if I wouldn't change it to another service, maybe something different, so I don't want to *WebPage* "know" how *Logic* works.

Is there any better solution?
Something I could do in *Logic* project which would make *WebPage* know how to connect to *Service*?

I'm getting exception:
`Could not find default endpoint element that references contract`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is to configure Logic by placing the endpoints in the code instead of the configuration file. When you create your web service client, use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574927.aspx), which takes a Binding and EndpointAddress as parameters. In the code of your Logic class, just supply those parameters in the code instead of letting it read them automatically from the config file.

Comment: It's better for me, but I would rather have sth in config. I'd like to (if possible) change endpoint without recompiling

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following...if you want to put it in a config file, why not just put it in the WebApp.config file? You could also just leave it in the config file for Logic. Then when you want to create your client, just read the Logic config file manually and extract the endpoint and binding data you need, so you can pass them into the client constructor.